# JavaScript - Sound does not play along with random values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, audio, random

I have a function that displays a random word from an array of objects, in a non-repeated way.

My goal is to make it play a sound clip with each word (that sound would be the word's pronounciation).

But, for some reason, I don't get any sound, in any browser, nor do any error messages show up. What can the cause be?

This is what I am working with:

```js
const p = document.getElementById("randomWord");
const myWords = [
    {
       text: "alpha",
       audio: "alpha.mp3"
    },
        {
       text: "bravo",
       audio: "bravo.mp3"
    },
        {
       text: "charlie",
       audio: "charlie.mp3"
    },
        {
       text: "delta",
       audio: "delta.mp3"
    },
    {
       text: "echo",
       audio: "echo.mp3"
    }
 ];
 let remainingWords = [];

function randomize() {
  if (remainingWords.length === 0) remainingWords = myWords.slice();
  let length = remainingWords.length;
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  const word = remainingWords[randomIndex];
  remainingWords.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  console.log(word);
  console.dir(p);
  p.textContent = word.text;
  document.getElementById("soundClip").play(word.audio);
}
```

```html
    <audio id="soundClip">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
    <button onclick="randomize()" type="button">Random Word</button>
    <p id="randomWord"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HTMLMediaElement.play()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) does not accept a parameter, and you're trying to pass in one.

Unused parameters are not a fatal error in JavaScript; they just aren't used, so for all intents and purposes you're calling just `.play()`.

Since the `<audio>` element has no source associated with it, nothing plays.

Try

```
const audioElement = document.getElementById("soundClip");
audioElement.src = word.audio;
audioElement.play();
```

instead.